# Probability of winning at least a single raffle as a function of raffles entered

Tags: probability

Had this question pop up in my head today, and not successful in solving it myself.
Say there is an infinite number of raffles, with a winning rate of 'p' each. How will the graph look? How can I calculate (using an algorithm) the probability of winning at least one if I enter 'n' raffles?
I can do this manually at smaller numbers (and kinda see a pattern) but not successful in figuring it out at a larger scale.

Meanwhile I have:

```
# 1 - 0.01
# 2 - 0.01^2 + 2*0.01*0.99 = 0.0199
# 3 - 0.01^3 + 3*0.01^2*0.99 + 3*0.01*0.99^2 = 0.029701
# 4 - 0.01^4 + 4*0.01^3*0.99 + 6*0.01^2*0.99^2 + 4*0.99^3*0.01 = 0.03940399
# 5 - 0.01^5 + 5*0.01^4*0.99 + 10*0.01^3*0.99^2 + 10*0.01^2*0.99^3 + 5*0.01*0.99^4 = 0.0490099501
# 6 - 0.01^6 + 6*0.01^5*0.99 + 15*0.01^4*0.99^2 + 20*0.01^3*0.99^3 + 15*0.01^2*0.99^4 + 6*0.01*0.99^5 = 0.05851985059
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have discovered the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)!

The neat trick here is not to increase the numbers and say "what if I won $1, 2, 3,$ etc. raffles out of $n$?" Instead, figure out the probability of winning zero raffles, then subtract that from $1$ to get the probability of NOT winning zero raffles, that is, winning at least one raffle.

For instance,

```
# 1 - 0.01 = 1 - 0.99
# 2 - 0.0199 = 1 - 0.99^2
# 3 - 0.029701 = 1 - 0.99^3
# 4 - 0.03940399 = 1 - 0.99^4
# 5 - 0.0490099501 = 1 - 0.99^5
# 6 - 0.05851985059 = 1 - 0.99^6
```

This is uses the [Complement Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event#Complement_rule). Next to Bayes Rule it's one of the most useful things you can learn in an introductory probability class.

Comment: Technically it's the Negative Binomial distribution.

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe this hasn't popped into my head. I'll blame the fact it's 4AM here and disregard the option that I'm just dumb. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, just because this popped into my head while trying to solve this the idiotic way - say there are 'n' bits, and I want to turn on 'k' of them. How many possibilities are there to do so?

Comment: Don't sweat it, there's a lot of little techniques and it takes tons of practice to intuit which one to use when.